# How to achieve single sign on?

Tags: php, magento, single-sign-on, odoo

I am new for single sign on. My system has three different instances with different applications 1.Openerp 2.Magneto 3.Php web site and in all applications my user and password is same. I am getting confused from where I should start.
can I use OAuth for this or which will be simplest way to achieve single sign on
I can also have LDAP is necessary.

Comment: How about manipulating the sessions to have a few universal identifiers if they live on the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a common database for all this, you can achieve this by writing few API's.

And use a kind of tokenization approach. That means when a user enters valid credentials, you create a token and store it in db for that user and return the same token as a response.

Use the same token to set it as browser session or cookie, and now across different application i.e 1.Openerp 2.Magneto 3.Php web site read the above cookie/session, if it is set, log them in.

Comment: I have different databases .for openerp postgres and for magento and php-mysql and instances are Ubuntu

Comment: Even then you can achieve it by setting this user token

Comment: okay . so for what purpose i need to write api. just to send Token in all apps? and how can i store token in session?                                                             please correct me if I am not on same page

Comment: API was a generic term which I used this is nothing but a PHP code that log you in, but along with that it sets a cookie or a session. Now once it sets it in browser you use this to read for other environments too

Comment: I will try this approch and will get back to you if I face any issue :) thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable to read let's say a cookie or session variable. That could come in handy if you want to manually implement the single sign on. On the other hand you can use OpenID you should look into that it might be useful

Comment: Is it secure using cookie? and how can I use session. on which app should I write code. I have seen some sites for openid . but I am not clear abou how to implement that in real picture.and also forget to mention that I have ubuntu instances.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use oauth to achieve single sign on after looking at your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign-on (SSO) is a way to authenticate users on multiple related, but independent software systems. Once logged in, a user can switch from one system to the next without the need to login again. Conversely, single sign-off is a way to log out and terminate access to multiple software systems with a single sign-off action.

for more info about single sign on see this link

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201206x1

and for applying this mechanism on openerp see this link

http://acespritechblog.com/2012/09/29/how-openerp-works-as-sso/

you can also if you are technical guy have a look on this module

https://www.odoo.com/apps/6.0/smile_sso/